# The French EAT or EATS (nationality-verb)

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

[image]

As for '**nationality-verb agreement**' (subject-verb agreement) why is that the answer is wrong?

Is this equal to Frenchmen= The French?

Comment: This use of an adjective *without* explicitly specifying the "missing" noun (as in ***The poor** are always with us*) is always treated as plural. And offhand I can't think of any contexts where the definite article *(**the**)* isn't *also* required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expressions like [**the French**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-french), [**the British**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-british) et cetera, when referring to people who live in those countries, are always considered to be plural:

> the French
>
> (functioning as plural)
>   the natives, citizens, or inhabitants of France collectively

That's why saying **the French are/do** is considered correct while **the French is/does** is not. **The French**, by the way, is really just a shorter way to say **the French people**.